# OpenGL ES 2: GLSurface View Showing Black Screen When SetContentView is set to an XML File

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview

I'm fairly new to OpenGL and my problem is when I do `SetContentView("R.layout.main")` nothing happens, however when I do `SetContentView("mGLView")`the game is displayed fine. My main.xml file contains an surface view and therefore I would of thought that it would be displayed, since main.xml has an surface view.

I suspect a way to fix this, will be done with addview or findviewbyid, however my implication of this have failed.

Relevent MainActivity Code:

```
public class OpenGLES20Activity extends Activity {
private GLSurfaceView mGLView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

main.xml code:

```
    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <SurfaceView 
android:id="@+id/SurfaceView" 
android:layout_width="500dp" 
android:layout_height="478dp">
</SurfaceView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Timer"
                android:id="@+id/Timer"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set **your** extended `GLSurfaceView` instead of just `SurfaceView` in the xml file so just change `SurfaceView` to `com.example.yourapp.MyGLSurfaceView`:

```
<com.example.yourapp.MyGLSurfaceView 
    android:id="@+id/SurfaceView" 
    android:layout_width="500dp" 
    android:layout_height="478dp"/>
```

Comment: I have made the change in my code and now I have the following error Error:(31, 19) error: constructor MyGLSurfaceView in class MyGLSurfaceView cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context,AttributeSet
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Your constructor needs to be `MyGLSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` like shown in the documentation I have linked you.

Comment: My constructor is set to that and I still get the error. 
If this helps my IDE has indicated this to be an problem: mGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);

Comment: Yeah you should remove that line

Comment: I have mGLView.onResume() and mGLView.onResume() what should I set them to? as MyGLSurfaceView.onResume() does not work.

Comment: Extend them from inside of the MyGLSurfaceView class